# Is it possible to type in a CSS border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website at the moment and i've run into a problem. In my CSS code i have the a border that is left of some social icons. It makes a 50 pixel box beside my social content.

Is it possible for me to type into the 50px border box? I want to use an external font that has icons within the font and use them in the border box

**CSS:**

```
google {
border-left: 50px solid #db4a39;
color: #db4a39;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;

}
```

If i can not type into the border can someone suggest an alternative option for me?

Comment: You could try using border images.

Comment: i never thought of that, thanks elclanrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a 50px-wide `<div>` to the left of the current one, instead of a border, is a pretty good solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KzMKB/

Edit: my motivation for the extra `<div>` is that this kind of stuff belongs in a child element, not shoe-horned into a border, in my opinion. It's semantically logical, and it's easy to put whatever kind of content you want into the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :before pseudo-element if you do not have control over markup.

Remove `border` from original element and set `margin-left` to 50px;

```
google {
    margin-left:50px;
    color: #db4a39;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
google:before {
    content: "hello";
    margin-left:-50px;
    background-color: #db4a39;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    width:50px;
    height:100%;
}
```

See full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6zX8y/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can move text into the border with the text-indent property.

```
#border-box {
  text-indent:-10px;
}
```